# facebook apprequests : An error occurred. Please try again later

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm using this code to send app requests to users in my facebook application

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

     window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
     FB.init({
         appId: '39764546513545342',
         status: true,
         cookie: true,
         oauth: true
     });
 };


           function invitetoevent(rid)
               {
              FB.ui({
                   method: 'apprequests',
                   message: 'i\'ll see you in this event.',
            title: 'Lets Go!.',
            filters: ['app_users'],
            max_recipients: 25,
                },
                 function (response) {
                        if (response.request && response.to) 
                            {
                //actions
                            } 
                        else 
                        {
                            //alert('canceled');
                        }
});

}
```

Comment: Please trim down this wall of code. [Stack Overflow is not going to read all that.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787/156418)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it doesn't make any sense but this code works fine.

i removed the facebook script loading from the previous page and used this code.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : '397334655643214', // App ID
  channelUrl : '//www.itradegame.com/channel.html', // Channel File
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});
```

Comment: I think you might be using the social plugins in that page already which renders the facebook script :)

Comment: do you mean like loading the script twice?!

Comment: yes, it could be the reason. Otherwise how it would work without the facebook script :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the way you are using filter is wrong.

**[DEMO](http://www.fbrell.com/saved/f2a665342d3c1dfd4882ca4c003415b9)**

PS: Assuming your callback function is correct

Comment: i'm using the same function on another app and it is working.

Comment: requests do not even need permissions/extended perms, so there must is a syntax error in your code